# Realizar reload do arquivo sem restart

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tem como realizar o reload do arquivo sem restart da aplicação:
- tenho um arquivo de `config.json`, esse arquivo é alterado as vezes, só que a API não identifica essa configuração nova, somente depois que restarta a aplicação.

```
nconf.argv()    
    .env()
    .file('package', 'package.json')    
    .file({
        file: path.join(__dirname,'../caminho', process.env.NODE_ENV + '.json')        
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`fs.watchFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) para verificar alterações neste arquivo e então realizar a ação necessária:

```
const path = request('path');
const fs = request('fs');

const CAMINHO = path.join(__dirname,'../caminho', process.env.NODE_ENV + '.json');

fs.watchFile(CAMINHO, (atual, anterior) => {
  console.log(`O horário de modificação anterior é: ${anterior.mtime}`);
  console.log(`O horário de modificação atual é: ${atual.mtime}`);
});
```

> [**`fs.watchFile`**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)
>
> Watch for changes on filename. The callback listener will be called each time the file is accessed.

Em tradução livre:

> Observa as mudanças no nome do arquivo. O callback listener será chamado sempre que o arquivo for acessado.